# Question about "using" keyword

Tags: c++

I'm well aware of using namespaces however, every now and then I'm stumbling upon a using, which uses a specific class. For instance :

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
(...)
```

However - every now and then, I'm seeing :

```
using std::string;
```

How should I interpret the "using" in this case ?

Cheers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

using std::string simply imports std::string into the current scope (aka, you can just use 'string' rather than 'std::string') without importing everything from ::std into the current scope.

---

edit: clarification after comment.

Comment: The purpose of doing this is to not pollute your current namespace with EVERYTHING from another namespace. The std namespace, for instance, holds a LOT of stuff. If you don't happen to need most of it, it's kind of silly to do 'using std' and bring it all in.

Comment: A general guideline is to never use the "using ..." in library headers as you pollute the namespace for the users of the library. Keep in mind: there is no way to undo a "using".

Answer (score 12):

`using namespace foo` allows you to access all names in the namespace foo without qualification. `using foo::bar` allows you to use `bar` without qualification, but not any other names in foo.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it allows you to bind to a specific type within a namespace without qualification.  As opposed to the first case which allows you to bind to any type.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to use `string` class without putting std:: before it. However if you want to use something else for example a vector then you need to use `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

too make things more complicated it's possible to do that:

```
class Base {
protected:
    void f();
};
class Fun: public Base {
public:
    using Base::f;
};
```

and now you have nice public method.